# How to pass a onclick event into a method to dismiss dialog after completion in Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

Trying to create a generic function to do custom dialog box, running into an issue with dismissing the dialog box from itself, here is my code in the activity. I am trying to finish the dialog but not the activity. I also can't reference the alertDialog to do .dismiss() from the calling class. Any ideas? Yes I can technically have a showPopupMessage for every time I want to show this popup and do the onclick inside of it easily. I am trying to make a generic app wide one where I just set the onclicklistener outside the method and pass it in.

```
 case R.id.deleteText:
                            final Context context = this;
                            View.OnClickListener rightEvent = new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    deleteCard(btCardToken);
                                    finish();
                                }
                            };
                            showPopupMessage(context,"Company", "Are you sure you wish to delete this card?", "CANCEL", "YES", rightEvent);
                            break;
```

Then my code in my generic class,

```
public void showPopupMessage(Context context, String header, String message, String leftButtonText, String rightButtonText, View.OnClickListener rightEvent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflator = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    View promptsView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_prompt, null);

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

    // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

    final StyledTextView alertHeader = (StyledTextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.alertHeader);
    final StyledTextView alertText = (StyledTextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.alertText);
    final StyledTextView rightButton = (StyledTextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
    final StyledTextView leftButton = (StyledTextView)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
    final EditText inputEditTextBox = (EditText)promptsView.findViewById(R.id.inputEditTextBox);

    alertHeader.setText(header);
    alertText.setText(message);
    inputEditTextBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    leftButton.setText(leftButtonText);
    rightButton.setText(rightButtonText);

    // set dialog message
    alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

    // create alert dialog
    final AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            alertDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    rightButton.setOnClickListener(rightEvent);
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Not getting exactly what you want to do??? your calling view click listener which is finishing the activity.

Comment: I want to do dismiss not finish.

Comment: So on dismiss of dialog you want to run that **deletecard()** method code, Right???

Comment: If you want to do that what i get then i do have a solution. Let me know if i am correct.

Comment: Yea your delegate looks to be the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a dialog by extending `DialogFragment` and creating a `AlertDialog` in the `onCreateDialog()` callback method. To deliver the dialog clicks, define an interface with a method for each type of click event. Then implement that interface in the host component that will receive the action events from the dialog.

Your dialog could look something like this:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    // Use this instance of the interface to deliver action events
    MyDialogListener mListener;

    // Override the Fragment.onAttach() method to instantiate the NoticeDialogListener
    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        // Verify that the host activity implements the callback interface
        try {
            // Instantiate the MyDialogListener so we can send events to the host
            mListener = (MyDialogListener) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            // The activity doesn't implement the interface, throw exception
            throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement MyDialogListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Build the dialog and set up the button click handlers
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        // Get the layout inflater
        LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
        builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_text_prompt, null))
        // Inflate and set the layout for the dialog
        // Pass null as the parent view because its going in the dialog layout
        final StyledTextView alertHeader = (StyledTextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.alertHeader);
        final StyledTextView alertText = (StyledTextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.alertText);
        final StyledTextView rightButton = (StyledTextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.rightButton);
        final StyledTextView leftButton = (StyledTextView) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.leftButton);
        final EditText inputEditTextBox = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.inputEditTextBox);

        alertHeader.setText(header);
        alertText.setText(message);
        inputEditTextBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        leftButton.setText(leftButtonText);
        rightButton.setText(rightButtonText);

        // set dialog message
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onLeftClicked(MyDialog.this);
            }
        });
        rightButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onRightClicked(MyDialog.this);
            }
        });
        return builder.create();
    }

    /* The activity that creates an instance of this dialog fragment must
     * implement this interface in order to receive event callbacks.
     * Each method passes the DialogFragment in case the host needs to query it. */
    public interface MyDialogListener {
        public void onLeftClicked(DialogFragment dialog);
        public void onRightClicked(DialogFragment dialog);
    }
}
```

In your activity, call the dialog and respond to the button clicks like so,

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
                          implements MyDialog.MyDialogListener{
    ...

    public void showMyDialog() {
        // Create an instance of the dialog fragment and show it
        DialogFragment dialog = new MyDialog();
        dialog.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "MyDialog");
    }

    // The dialog fragment receives a reference to this Activity through the
    // Fragment.onAttach() callback, which it uses to call the following methods
    // defined by the MyDialog.MyDialogListener interface
    @Override
    public void OnLeftClicked(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's left button
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onRightClicked(DialogFragment dialog) {
        // User touched the dialog's right button
        ...
    }
}
```

For more info you can check the official docs: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Comment: This is looks to be the answer, yea i should have built it using a delegate. I would up vote but I don't have the ability yet.

Comment: @JamesWyman, that is ok. I don't answer for up-votes ;).  If this works for you, feel free to mark it as answers so others can get benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

You need to rework many things, `Dialog.show()` is not meant to be called by your program manually. You should use DialogFragment, and FragmentManager to manage the dialog show, hide etc.

If you do not follow the DialogFragment route, you would face lots and lots of trouble later, until you realize you HAVE to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the AlertDialog `setPositiveButton()` method for YES and `setNegativeButton()` method for NO and handle their clicks

Answer (score 0):

Is setting onClickListener  after showing dialog not working?

```
  alertDialog.show();

  leftButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        alertDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
rightButton.setOnClickListener(rightEvent);
```